# sql rows containing column twice (or more)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

using **PhpMyAdmin**, I am trying to retrieve a list of rooms that have **all** of a given set of facilities. I am able to query a table of rooms with facilities that I want, but I don't know how to filter out the rooms that appear for every facility.

Here is what I query:

```
SELECT distinct * FROM `Facilities` WHERE `Facility` = 'DVD Player' UNION
SELECT distinct * from `Facilities` WHERE `Facility` = 'Computer';
```

When I use    `Group By 'Room' Having Count(Distinct 'Room') = 2` I get the right table with this order but if i select `Computer` and then union it and select `DVD Player`, I **don't** get the correct table.

My initial query before any grouping shows this:

```
Room    | Facility
A.0.0.1   Computer
G.0.02    Computer
HH.0.23   Computer
G.0.02    DVD Player
HH.0.23   DVD Player
```

I want the rooms that have both Computer and DVD Player. I have 22 Facilities in my table and I may want to be able to query any combination of them to find the matching rooms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want rooms that have a particular set of facilities, try something like this:

```
select f.room
from facilities f
where f.facility in ('Computer', 'DVD Player')
group by f.room
having count(distinct f.facility) = 2;
```